# Cortana Bot Time Out

Tags: azure, chatbot, cortana

I created a bot in SAP CAI and integrated the bot with Microsoft Azure.  Testing the bot in Azure's webchat was successful.  I want the bot to be voice-activated, so I connected the bot with Cortana.

I was able to call the bot and give permission for use on my phone's Cortana app.  However, when I invocate the bot afterwards, the bot times out.

[Cortana Conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKqDp.jpg)

Text version of conversation:

> *Me: Tell Work Order Notification (Work Order Notification = Invocation Name)*
>
> *Cortana: I'm getting you connected to my-awesome-vaam-bot...*
>
> *C: Working on it.*
>
> *C: Working on it.*
>
> *C: Sorry, but my-awesome-vaam-bot isn't responding right now. Try again later.*

In the Azure portal, under the Channels tab, I received two errors after each invocation:

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout
>
> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code BadRequest

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you explain how you integrated the SAP CAI bot with Azure? From your error messages, it looks like your front end (Azure's webchat) is  not communicating with  your backend (your SAP CAI bot).

Comment: I used the connect feature in CAI to integrate with Azure.  I found the Microsoft App ID and Password from Azure and pasted it into CAI.  When I test the bot in Azure's Portal in "Test in Webchat," the bot works correctly.  Therefore, I think it is an issue between my integration with Azure and Cortana.  Its especially weird that my Cortana app recognizes the bot, it just cannot invocate it.